# Is there a static Groovy call operator?

Tags: groovy

I know I can create a call operator for a Groovy class like this:

```
class MyCallable {
    int call(int x) {           
        2*x
    }
}

def mc = new MyCallable()
assert mc(2) == 4
```

But can I create a *static* call method?

```
class MyStaticCallable {
    static int call(int x) {           
        2*x
    }
}

assert MyStaticCallable(2) == 4
```

Many thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you'd have to do

```
MyStaticCallable.call(2)
```

Comment: Many thanks @tim_yates! I ended up kind of faking it with `import static`.